# Javascript prototype and closures

Tags: javascript

Given this code:

```
function Test(){
    var $D = Date.prototype;
    $D.addDays=function(value){this.setDate(this.getDate()+value);return this;};
    $D.clone = function() {
        return new Date(this.getTime());
    };
    alert(new Date().addDays(5));
    var x = 5;
}

Test();

alert(new Date().addDays(1));
​alert(x);​
```

The only error is thrown by `alert(x)` which throws the "x is undefined" error, because x is limited to function `Test()`

The call to `addDays()` works both within the function and outside it.

I'm assuming this is because the scope of the Date prototype is global, so it's irrelevant that I extend it within a closure.

So if I wanted to extend Date within a closure, BUT NOT allow any other javascript to get the extension, how would I do it?

The reason I'm asking is because when I'm extending core javascript objects, I don't want to conflict with other libraries which may make the same modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do what you're talking about. You can just delete your changes when you're done:

```
function Test() {
    var $D = Date.prototype;
    // ...
    delete $D.addDays;
    delete $D.clone;
}
```

This would work if you needed the methods only during a single execution. It wouldn't work if you need the methods to be available indefinitely, but only within your module.

If that's not the case, you can add the extension methods directly to the Date objects you (not to the prototype). Within your module, you could have a function that creates these special `Date` objects for you:

```
function createDate() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.method1 = function() { ... };
    d.method2 = function() { ... };
    return d;
}
```

Finally, you can use helper functions scoped within your closure instead of extending the prototype. Really, extending the prototype is just syntactic sugar for you in this case anyway.

Comment: This works only if you want to add them temporarily. You cannot e.g. expose functions depending on those prototype functions, since they are deleted by the time the function is called (some time in the future). In the end, `Date.prototype` is shared no matter where it is extended.

Comment: Can you copy an object and extend the copy?

Comment: @pimvdb You are right. I was making the assumption that the methods would only be needed temporarily. I reworded my first approach to address this.